# How do I get the current Url from within a FilterAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, authorization, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I am writing an Authorize filter attribute adn I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the current url as a string so I can pass it as a parameter to the LogOn action. The goal is that if a user successfully logs on, they will be redirected to the page they were originally trying to access.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizeContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

    ... my auth code ...
    bool isAuth ;
    ... my auth code ...

    if(!isAuth)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary { 
                { "Area", "" }, 
                { "Controller", "Account" }, 
                { "Action", "LogOn" },
                { "RedirectUrl", "/Url/String/For/Currnt/Request" } // how do I get this?
            }
        );
    }
}
```

How do I get the full string Url from the current request?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try:

```
var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
```

Comment: You could also use RawUrl (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl) to get url without domain

Answer (score 19):

To get the complete `URL` you can try as suggested by the `@rboarman` but usually the `RedirectUrl` will be the **relative url** and for that you have to try the the `RawUrl` property of the `Request` object.

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url  ===> http://somesite.com/admin/manage

filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl ====> /admin/manage
```

**EDITED: Fixed the second example**

Comment: Did you mean for "RawUrl" to be used in your 2nd example?

Comment: -1 Observing the value of `Url` does not magically make it absolute then relative.

Comment: @JoshNoe Yes I meant the RawUrl in the second example. I'm little away from SO nowadays and I missed to see your comment.

Answer (score 7):

In my specific case I was after the `UrlReferrer` URL.

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer
```

This one let me redirect the user back to the page he was before trying to access an action he doesn't have permission to access.

Answer (score 5):

This is the highest ranked result on Google so in Asp.net Core 2.0 this is how I'm doing it:

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Url();
```

using this extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the absolute url.
/// </summary>
public static string Url(this HttpRequest request)
{
    return $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}{request.Path}{request.QueryString}";
}
```